# How to classify gameplay situations with CNNs (in soccer analytics)

Tags: computer-vision, deep-learning, lstm

even though I don't have a particular code question, I try to explain my story + ask my questions as precise and specific as possible. I'm sort of a ML rookie and I've recently spent some time to understand the basics of computer vision and deep learning to get a little project of mine going. I am a huge soccer/football fanatic and am passionate about game analytics and game tactics. As I've learned more about CV and DL in a CS class I took at college, I thought that a combination of both might be an interesting approach (I'm aware that it is not a new topic in sports broadcasting).

https://media.giphy.com/media/jl2rOaO1P3m92/giphy.gif

This gif is a concrete example of a gameplay sequence that is highly useful for the game outcome (create a chance to score a goal): A player running towards the goal, passing to another player, in doing so taking 4 opponents off the game and creating (almost) a big chance to score. Clearly this type of pass is way more useful (valuable) than just a random pass from A to B somewhere within the own half from left to right.

Game statistics these days do not really take into consideration the quality of an action, rather consider the quantity of certain events (like passes in general, possession, duels etc.). So I wonder if (considered the availability of such video footage)

1. it might be able to classify the quality of such gameplay scenarios with a CNN/RNN for example (-> not only a random pass, but a pass in the final third of the pitch, played vertically (i.e. towards the opponent goal), taking off X opponent players etc.)
2. if a CPU/GPU can even process such amounts of data in real-time (considered that soccer is a rather dynamic sport where 22 players move at the same time all the time)
3. if data quality (video footage) like above is high enough

I've already talked to PhD students about this. They told me that I should consider taking intermediate steps (like classifying the basic pass direction first). They also mentioned LTSM and Deep Reinforcement Learning (even though I don't really have an agent as I'm not controlling any game or simulation; so I'm not sure about if DRL is applicable then).

I'd be super happy if someone could provide me with some more hints so that I can do more specific research. Just like: 'yes it is possible, just go and search for X or consider y'. Or 'no because read about abc'.

Thanks so much + sorry to bother!

Answer (score 0):

This will be an extension of activity recognition using video. There is already a fair amount of research on it. You can have a good look at the topic, and also competitions like ActivityNet.

LSTM, 3D CNN based architectures and Facebook's C3D are good examples that can analyze videos and come up with this sort of results. I have tried the first two and had some good results with datasets like VIRAT and KTH (basic activities), but the third was too big for my GPU.

My suggestion is to start with something simple like [this](https://github.com/inubushi/LSTM-KTH), and then build up on it to find both data and architectures that match your task better.